# 502 Bad Gateway Keeps on Happening

Tags: nginx

This has been driving me nuts for a couple of hours now. But I was following a course and he was using this gist: https://gist.github.com/bradtraversy/cfa565b879ff1458dba08f423cb01d71

But No matter what I do I get a 502 Bad Gateway.

Here's the conf from the gist (that I followed but changed a few names like the folder, username, etc).

```
    listen 80;
    server_name YOUR_IP_ADDRESS;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/djangoadmin/pyapps/btre_project;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/djangoadmin/pyapps/btre_project;    
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Here's what I used (I tried other things from StackOverflow answers ,but the result is the same)

```
    listen 80;
    server_name MYIP:8000;

    root /var/www/html;

     location / {
             proxy_pass MYIP:8000;
             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
             proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
             root /home/myname_is/pyapps/Profile-Badges;
              }
     }
```

Can anyone help, please

Comment: You've changed quite a lot of things in that config. Practically all of it, actually!

Comment: I tried to follow this other StackOverflow Thread trying to fix it but still not working... I used both configs btw. But what I meant when I said I changed a few things is that when the instructor said to use this folder, I used a different name to fit what I'm trying to do. So you can see that there he used `btre` and I used `Profile-Badges`

Comment: Again, you have changed many more things than that. Compare the two configs. They're nothing alike. Get it working with the instructions first then change things _one at a time_ if you need to. When it breaks, you'll know what caused it.

Comment: Look in the error log for the cause of the 502 error. But your `proxy_pass` statement needs a scheme.

Comment: @RichardSmith

``` 2019/06/09 06:26:12 [error] 29422#29422: *27 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 5.165.4.96, server: 1MYIP, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "MyIP/", host: "MyIP"